# regex: how to match last ',' in string "text part one, text part two, text part three,"

Tags: regex

I am using this regex

```
/(?![""])(,)(?![""])/g
```

to match all commas in my given comma separated string between the " ".

```
 "this is a text","text part one, text part two, text part three,","another text","more text",
```

The comma after 'three' is not matched...
Thanks for any useful hints!

Comment: The given regex doesn't really do what you describe. While the first lookahead is pointless, the second one makes the regex fail, as the comma in question is directly followed by `"`. Apart from that, the question is lacking a lot of detail, starting with the language in use.

Comment: Sorry - i've tried to give a more precise example. I have a string build of comma-separated parts that are enclosed in " " and i want to match all commas in all enclosed parts.... I am testing that in regex101.com ... https://regex101.com/r/wC5tR6/1

Comment: How are you getting the text? Because it looks like there's some bad stuff going on there.

Answer (score 0):

This could probably be better done with some kind of lookahead but since I'm not sure exactly what you're after, I'll throw these ideas out there.

Loaded your string into a testfile "testtxt" and ran some perl one-liners on it to play around.  I used substitution to demonstrate the matches.

To just get rid of the last comma:

```
perl -ple 's/,(")/$1/g' testtxt
"text part one, text part two, text part three"
```

To get rid of all commas inside the quotes:

```
perl -ple 's/,//g' testtxt
"text part one text part two text part three"
```

To strip everything but the commas in the string:

```
perl -ple 's/[^,]//g' testtxt
,,,
```

Answer (score 0):

A comma appear in a text only after word(s), so a potential regex might be:

```
 /\w+(,)/g
```

It is matching one to N words, and capture the comma after them.
Available result here: https://regex101.com/r/vJ0hY5/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex as : `/\w+(,)(?=\")/g`

Above regex getting `'` preceded by `word` and followed by `"`

[Demo and Explaination](https://regex101.com/r/xO6wP1/1)